# Failed to connect localhost:8081 in Kafka Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have started zookeeper and Kafka with below commands:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

when I tried to get Schema Registry compatibility settings(Backward, forward, none), I ran below curl command:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/config
```

Expected:

```
{"compatibility":"BACKWARD"}
```

result:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Connection refused
```

how can I find out which port to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you have only started Zookeeper and Kafka, but not the Schema Registry.

If you did start it, and see that it is listening in the terminal output on port 8081, then curl should work

You can refer to the [Schema Registry configuration](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/config.html#schemaregistry-config) for setting up the port (or `listeners`)

Comment: thanks for your help, starting schema-registry from confluent.io solved my problem.